# Managing remote WMI connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

I code in mostly VBScript and have a question regarding a C# ASP.NET application that I'm writing that will do remote WMI queries for information (specifically to Systems Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)). The examples shown in the SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc145284.aspx) for Config Mgr 2007 show a connection being created to the remote server and calling snipplets (methods) in another class.  However, in this application I would be making numerous calls to the remote server and I'm curious to know how C# manages and closes this connection?  If I called multiple 'snipplets', does it maintain a single connection to the server or would each 'snipplet' called create a new connection to the server.  My concern is having 300 connections to the server because I don't see an .Close or any cleanup of the connection.  I would just like to ensure my class is built properly and not making a multitude of connections to the remote server before I continue building my application.  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see these 300 connections??

Net management Classes are finally based on the WMI COM interfaces and classes;Even there, you'll missing a "Close". From what I think [ :-) ]
and my experience, the connection will disappear automatically, if your
objects are all properly disposed.

What I recommend, is, create a ManagementScope first and use it all
the time in your other methods and queries. Finally, get rid of it.

You should show one of your methods, to become more specific!

br++mabra